# Permission Denied while trying to install ruby gems on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, ubuntu, permissions

I am trying to install ruby gems on my computer running Ubuntu 16.04. I use bash with the oh-my-zsh framework.

When I run the command:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

I get the error message:

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template '/usr/share/rvm/rvm-exec-test.XXXXXX': Permission denied
```

How do I set up the permissions for this to work properly?

Comment: Have you made sure the the path is writeable? you can use ls -la to verify this. You can also try using sudo before your command as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any leftovers from a previous ruby installation:

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove rvm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then find any residue from the rvm package (the --mount option is to avoid the /mnt folder, useful when using wsl).

```
sudo find / -name "rvm" -mount
```

Then remove all remaining rvm directories (for example):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc/rvm
```

Then install again with this:

```
sudo apt install gnupg2
gpg2 --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

If an error occurs on the last line, try:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

Works for me, on Ubuntu 22 LTS with WSL

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby
```

**NOTE**: Running a script as sudo can be very dangerous if you don't know what it is actually doing. Make sure to check the script and if possible give the appropriate permissions to the required files and or folders it needs to access. For some more info regarding why it can be dangerous see https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/448/why-is-running-commands-with-sudo-dangerous

Quick example with your particular use case, as can be seen in the link:

"...If a website is asking you to curl http://link/to/script | sudo bash, don't do that. Download the script, take a quick look, and after that, you can run it. Even if the original author did not intend to make the script malicious, someone might have compromised the original author's accounts and uploaded a new, "updated" script. You are the one responsible for your computer's integrity, and therefore you need to be familiar with your system's capabilities."

Comment: You should include at least some statement of the risks of running code that you haven't verified or inspected, and even more so if you encourage people to do that as root!

Comment: Fair enough, I'll add it in. Having said that rvm is quite reputable and this script isn't malicious. Here is a link to it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer

Comment: Adding 'sudo' before bash is the instruction (in the RVM instructions) for making a multi-user install.  To install as a single user, you have to use:
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
... which won't work, because RVM never works until you google and fight with each step for hours.

Answer (score -2):

Make The directory as read and write ... `cd dirname chmod 777`
or

```
sudo gem install 'gem name','version'
```